# Understanding closure in scala?

Tags: scala, closures

I am not even sure if this is about closures, but I cannot reason about `e` in the following code.

```
type Set = Int => Boolean

/* characteristic function of Set */
def contains(s: Set, elem: Int): Boolean = s(elem)

/* definition of a singleton set, returning a set of only one given element  */
def singletonSet(elem: Int): Set = e => e == elem
```

In the above code, where does the `e` come from? How can I reason about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't about closure. `e` simply represents an element of type `Int` as dictated by the declaration of the `Set` type, which is an alias for a `Function1[Int, Bool]`. Think of `e` as a placeholder for future `Int` values which you'll pass. This is simply [anonymous function syntax](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/anonymous-function-syntax.html).

When you call `singletonSet`, you'll have to pass the `Int` parameter which `e` will reflect:

```
println(contains(singletonSet(1), 1)) // yields true
println(contains(singletonSet(1), 2)) // yields false
```

The same would work if you passed an anonymous function directly:

```
println(contains(e => e == 1, 1))
```